# Turing Machine that outputs pi

Tags: code-challenge, pi

### Turing Machine Preliminaries

A Turing machine is specified by the following data

- A finite set of symbols S = \$\{s_1,s_2,...\}\$
- A finite set of states M = \$\{m_1,m_2,...\}\$
- A partially defined function
  $$T : M \times S \to S \times \{\mathrm{left},\mathrm{right}\} \times M   $$

Any encoding of such a Turing machine is acceptable, to fix conventions though an example encoding as used for example [at this online simulator](https://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) is to provide a list of lines of code, each line in the format

```
'<current state> <current symbol> <new symbol> <direction> <new state>'.
```

where it is understood that the Turing machine will write the new symbol at the head, move one unit in the specified direction, and enter the new state. Undefined behaviour defaults to halting the Turing machine.

### Problem Statement

There must be at least four symbols in your Turing machine, the blank symbol `_`, the decimal point `.`, and `0`, `1`. There must be at least one state 'begin'. The tape is a one-sided infinite tape, initialized to all blank symbols `['_','_','_',...]`. The Turing machine is initialized with the head pointing at the first symbol, in the 'begin' state. Write a turing machine that never halts, such that for any natural number n the there is some time \$T_n\$ for which after \$T_n\$ steps the Turing machine will never change the n-th symbol on the tape, so that the tape will limit to showing the binary decimal representation of pi:
$$11.0010010000111111011…$$
Your score is given by the number of states \$\times\$ the number of symbols in your Turing machine.

### Caveats

- If your Turing machine ever tries to go 'left' at the first symbol, it will halt

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! It's recommended to use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) for future challenges, so people can give feedback on your posts, and check if it's clear or a duplicate, etc.

Comment: It says the score is given by number of states * number of symbols. This is code-golf (shortest code wins), correct? If so, you might want to mention it explicitly and add the [tag:code-golf] tag. :)

Comment: @Steffan Thanks for the help, and yes. Just to mention rationale behind the scoring mechanism, the total number of turing machines for a given number M of states and S of symbols is (2*S*M)^(S*M), so S*M seemed like a reasonable objective scoring procedure. I know that there are algorithmic ways to convert between states and symbols as well, (e.g. any decision problem I believe can be done with just 2 states, or just 2 symbols).

Comment: "[...] showing the binary decimal representation of pi [...]": it's *binary*, not *binary decimal*.

Comment: Use http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf

Comment: https://tio.run/##JY5RC8IwDITf9yvy2GQZrB1VEfbs7xhYXLCOrXbKfn1NEQ5Cju@Om6f3M8RYyiq3AUZ4GMv20vOpZ4fwnUMKjZobJ84sqEQMGczOB45mIJW0Fv/XId/lYzYy7kzSWYetp4TGU0ZsAGSBA67a5mgjUapCyI52qiGvr0ZSdyjPmXau1eU1yTKuSZYMdWP5AQ